# filtering some text from line using sed linux

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I have a following content in the file:

```
NAME=ALARMCARDSLOT137 TYPE=2 CLASS=116 SYSPORT=2629 STATE=U ALARM=M APPL=" " CRMPLINK=CHASSIS131 DYNDATA="GL:1,15 ADMN:1 OPER:2 USAG:2 STBY:0 AVAL:0 PROC:0 UKNN:0 INH:0 ALM:20063;1406718801,"
```

I just want to filter out NAME , SYSPORT and ALM field using `sed`

Comment: Show your expected output. It's not clear, for example, whether the value of the `ALM field` should be `20063` or `20063;1406718801` or `20063;1406718801,` or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below sed command to filter out NAME,SYSPORT,ALM fields ,

```
$ sed 's/.*\(NAME=[^ ]*\).*\(SYSPORT=[^ ]*\).*\(ALM:[^;]*\).*/\1 \2 \3/g' file
NAME=ALARMCARDSLOT137 SYSPORT=2629 ALM:20063
```

Comment: hope field are in the same order (as in sample). So we can assume this

Answer (score 1):

why not using `grep`?

```
grep -oE 'NAME=\S*|SYSPORT=\S*|ALM:[^;]*'
```

test with your text:

```
kent$  echo 'NAME=ALARMCARDSLOT137 TYPE=2 CLASS=116 SYSPORT=2629 STATE=U ALARM=M APPL=" " CRMPLINK=CHASSIS131 DYNDATA="GL:1,15 ADMN:1 OPER:2 USAG:2 STBY:0 AVAL:0 PROC:0 UKNN:0 INH:0 ALM:20063;1406718801,"'|grep -oE 'NAME=\S*|SYSPORT=\S*|ALM:[^;]*'
NAME=ALARMCARDSLOT137
SYSPORT=2629
ALM:20063
```

Comment: if there are no field value having one of the filter value inside and return could be in 3 line per record ...

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `awk`

```
awk -F" |;" -v RS=" " '/NAME|SYSPORT|ALM/ {print $1}'
NAME=ALARMCARDSLOT137
SYSPORT=2629
ALM:20063
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever there are `name=value` pairs in input files, I find it best to first create an array mapping the names to the values and then operating on the array using the names of the fields you care about. For example:

```
$ cat tst.awk
function bldN2Varrs(    i, fldarr, fldnr, subarr, subnr, tmp ) {
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) { gsub(/ /,RS,$i) }

    split($0,fldarr,/[[:blank:]]+/)
    for (fldnr in fldarr) {
        split(fldarr[fldnr],tmp,/=/)
        gsub(RS," ",tmp[2])
        gsub(/^"|"$/,"",tmp[2])
        name2value[tmp[1]] = tmp[2]

        split(tmp[2],subarr,/ /)
        for (subnr in subarr) {
            split(subarr[subnr],tmp,/:/)
            subName2value[tmp[1]] = tmp[2]
        }
    }
}

function prt( fld, subfld ) {
    if (subfld) print fld "/" subfld "=" subName2value[subfld]
    else        print fld            "=" name2value[fld]
}

BEGIN { FS=OFS="\"" }
{
    bldN2Varrs()
    prt("NAME")
    prt("SYSPORT")
    prt("DYNDATA","ALM")
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
NAME=ALARMCARDSLOT137
SYSPORT=2629
DYNDATA/ALM=20063;1406718801,
```

and if `20063;1406718801,` isn't the desired value for the `ALM` field and you just want some subsection of that, simply tweak the array construction function to suit whatever your criteria is.